# Text-align:center not working on image inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a div in my app containing profile information like name, account #, and profile picture. For some reason the profile picture won't center even though I've tried the text-align:center trick. Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="profile-heading">
    <img alt="6dbepurq" src="http://anymarket.s3.amazonaws.com/users/avatars/000/000/015/medium/6dBEpuRQ.jpeg?1406690559">
    <h2>Tom Maxwell</h2>
    <p id="school">University of California, Berkeley</p>
    <p>User #15</p>
</div>
```

And the CSS for the #profile-heading div looks like this:

```
 #profile-heading {
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:50px;
  img{
    border-radius:50%;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
  }
  h2{
    font-weight:800;
    margin-bottom:5px;
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: seems to be working here... right? http://jsfiddle.net/r711e3ze/

Comment: It's not working on my production site, though

Comment: @karthikr - should have mentioned, I'm using Sass.

Comment: Your code have no problem. I try it [_HERE_](http://jsfiddle.net/manassornpn/a143jvzu/) and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

`img` tag by default is inline-block and you must use `text-align: center` in parent container to align `img` tag horizontally.
In case of it's `display` property value has been changed to `block` you should  set styles `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to center horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

When I un-nested your styles everything worked in centering the image:

```
#profile-heading {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:50px;
}
#profile-heading img {
    border-radius:50%;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}
#profile-heading h2 {
    font-weight:800;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Nested are only for CSS pre-processors using SASS or LESS.

Another way to center things is with auto left and right margins: `margin: 0 auto;` Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I'm using SASS, forgot to add that.

Comment: That's valid for SASS then. Try `position: relative` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Setting display property for img would do the trick:

```
#profile-heading {
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:50px;
  img{
    border-radius:50%;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    display: inline-block; /* added this line */
  }
  h2{
    font-weight:800;
    margin-bottom:5px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As  `<img>` tag is not a `block level` element which means `text-align` property will not work as expected. You can do 2 things to solve this issue.

1. Either apply `text-align: center`on parent element.
2. make the `<img>` tag a block level element using `display: inline-block;`.

You can see a **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/tufigufijeki/1/edit)** here.